# How to add a background image in an .apk?

Tags: image, background, addition

I am a noob and I want to add an backround image into an apk file which has no background.
Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) helped me when I was looking for this question :)

Harry

Comment: Thanks, but I want to ad an image not just a color